# A question relating to syntax

Tags: syntax

Which of the following sentence constructions is correct (or more commonly used)?

- Which slot in the washer did you put in the water?
  Or
- Which slot in the washer did you put the powder in?

A very simple question but please give me some explanations on why one is preferred over the other. I have always thought that 'put in' is a phrasal verb as in 'You have to put in the effort to succeed'.
While the second sentence seem more correct to me as 'put' is a transitive verb and since the sentence can be rearranged into 'In which slot did you put the powder', I felt that the proposition should be used to end the sentence.

Is what I said correct this a degree?

Many thanks

Comment: It would be very difficult to put a slot in the water, so your first option is a non-starter. Your second sentence is idiomatic, although it is difficult to visualize putting powder in a slot. _In which slot did you put the powder?_ is grammatical, but again, presents a physical difficulty. (If someone has taught you that you must not end a sentence with a preposition, you should tell them that this is nonsense; that is a "rule" invented out of thin air which has no basis in English grammar.)

Comment: Indeed some people have falsely claimed that I shouldn't end the sentence with a preposition. But does it sound better to leave the preposition at the start of the sentence or just more formal sounding. Thanks for the explanation, I just got a little confused as I have seen some people ask in a forum 'Which slot do I put in the detergent?' even though put is a transitive verb. However, since 'put in' is a phrasal verb, is it correct to leave out the object in everyday conversation e.g. Put in the rice please (please put the rice into the pot)? Or should I say 'put the rice in please'?

Comment: I would say that "put in" is *not* a phrasal verb, because both words have exactly their normal meaning: "to place", and "inside".  Therefore, there's nothing wrong with separating them.  What gets put in what is strictly a matter of word order  "X put in Y" = X went into Y.  "X put Y in" = Y went into X.

Comment: Assuming that the object is know (Y), can I just say 'please put in X' as short for 'please put into Y, the X.' Or does that lead to confusion with whether X goes into Y or Y goes into X? E.g. (Referring to a bowl) 'I want you to put in the ball' or 'put the ball in' to mean I want the ball in the bowl.

Comment: No, "put in the ball" is perfectly clear and understandable.  I realize this is a little confusing, because "the ball is put in the bowl" means the ball goes into the bowl, but "put in the ball" also means that the ball is going in!

Comment: @stangdon Soon we'll be driving ourselves round the bend with **Put the book in the bag on the table.** Our prepositions are as hard to control as greased pigs sometimes.

Comment: @JUNCINATOR It's sometimes good to keep "put" and "in" as close together as one can manage to reduce ambiguity. But the person who wrote "Which slot do I put in the detergent" is just plain wrong. It says that the speaker is putting the _slot_ in the _detergent!_ The correct form is "Which slot do I put the detergent in?"